# Xubuntu 16.04 - set mouse to *always* single click?

Tags: xubuntu, mouse

I have Xubuntu 16.04 and XFCE as my desktop environment. I have set my mouse to single click. Yet on the desktop I am forced to double click. Is there a way to set every selection of folders and files to single click?

Thank you.

Lobonca

Comment: I was under the impression [this bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8750) had been squashed...

Answer (score 2):

Single click to access items is done in two parts for Xfce.  Your Desktop and File Manager are set separately.

For the Desktop itself single click, go to your *Applications > Settings > Desktop* and in the Icons tab choose `Single click to activate items`.

[image]

Then in your *Applications > Settings > File Manager* in the Behavior tab, choose `Single click to activate items` and that should make it single click for you.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although I've upvoted this answer as it answers the question, please note this is _still_ not a universal solution. For example in Xubuntu 18.04, even after modifying both steps, catfish search refuses to respect any of them. So future searchers, be advised.